# Return value handling from Perl Package/Module

Tags: perl, module

I have written a perl package `Parsepw` which will parse the configuration file and returns the userid and password from config file to main script.

My module looks like this:

```
package Parsepw;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw(import);

our @EXPORT_OK = qw(parse_config_file);

sub parse_config_file {
    ...
    #reads the config file, if not found print error message here else using regex extract user and password line
    ...
    if ( $user && $ciphertext ){
        return ( $user, $ciphertext );
    }
}
1;
```

Below is my main script:

```
...
use Parsepw;

my ($user, $passwd) = Parsepw::parse_config_file();
print "$user, $passwd\n";
```

I am able to retrieve `user` and `passwd` in positive test scenario, but in negative test case how can I handle it.

If suppose `parse_config_file` subroutine couldn't able to parse the configuration file in the module how can I throw an error/warning to my main script? Since the return value I have is `$user, $passwd`, how can I have the error/warning message?

Without using package everything works fine if I put all the code in single script. I was trying to write separate package for first time.

Answer (score 4):

You could return nothing (zero scalars) when there's an error.

```
sub parse_config_file {
    ...

    if ( $user && $ciphertext ) {
        return ( $user, $ciphertext );
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

A list assignment in scalar returns the number of scalars returned by its right-hand side. This allows you to use

```
my ($user, $password) = parse_config_file(...)
   or die(...);

...
```

or

```
if ( my ($user, $password) = parse_config_file(...) ) {
   # Success
   ...
} else {
   # Error
   ...
}
```

---

You could throw an exception on error.

```
use Carp qw( croak );

sub parse_config_file {
    ...

    $user && $ciphertext
       or croak("...");

    return ( $user, $ciphertext );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I am using second method which you have mentioned in your answer and I have given a wrong configuration file name, so I can see what error message it will show while running. this is the message I am getting now `Use of uninitialized value $passwd in concatenation (.) or string at script.pl line 16.
Config file not found : /../../../config_file.cfg1,`. Actually it should show the message which was in else part `"Password retrieval error";`

Answer (score 0):

You have various options to design the part of your module's interface that deals with errors.

One way, as [ikegami says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61975894/203856), could be to use a bare `return`, and let the module's user to check the results from `parse_config_file`.

---

If you want to "throw an exception", Perl offers a mechanism to do that using `die` passing blessed references, but you'll have to build a hierarchy of exception classes yourself (other languages provide a built hierarchy).

The example starts with the code for `Foo.pm`.
It defines a minimal hierarchy of exception classes (`Foo::Exception` and `Foo::Exception::ParseError`).

As @ikegami pointed out, it's good practice to overload stringification: the reason is explained in the documentation for `die`:

> Because Perl stringifies uncaught exception messages before display, you'll probably want to overload stringification operations on exception objects. See overload for details about that.

In this case, I chose a minimalistic approach: strigifying an exception object will simply return its class name.

In the implementation for `parse_config_file`, we pass `die` an object to thrown a typed exception.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

package Foo::Exception;
use overload '""' => sub { ref(shift) };

sub new {
    return bless {}, shift;
}

package Foo::Exception::ParseError;
use base 'Foo::Exception';

### The rest of the package, as in the example
### in your original question

package Foo;

use Exporter qw(import);

our @EXPORT_OK = qw(parse_config_file);

sub parse_config_file {
    die Foo::Exception::ParseError->new();
}
1;
```

In the script that uses the library (`foo.pl`), we can use the usual `eval … if (@$) …` form to trap the exception and react according to its type. `$@` contains  in this case a blessed reference (in other words, an object) representing the exception: you could enrich the exception classes so that they can contain additional information about the state of the process when the error occurred.

```perl
use lib '.';

use Foo qw/parse_config_file/;

eval {
    parse_config_file();
};
if ($@) {
    if ($@->isa('Foo::Exception::ParseError')) {
        print "Error parsing file\n";
    }
    else {
        die "Unexpected error!";
    }
}

1;
```

Comment: @ikegami Right, that's why I added the specifier "at least the way it's common in other languages".  Good point on stringification (as the documentation for `die` says), I am going to edit my answer expanding the example to include that. And I'll point to alternatives like Exception::Class

Comment: Fair point, thanks.  Let me leave a more precise answer incorporating your remarks